# Data Stacking Issue PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, temporary-files

So, I have a client who wanted me to make a bulk domain checker. He wanted it to take in an untimed amount of domains and output them in a downloadable .csv file.
Everything works just like it should until you try to use it a second time.
Then it reopens the file and appends the data ontop of it.
So if you put in 500 domains the first time, it outputs 500 domains. If you put 500 domains in the second time, it outputs 1000 domains.
Its turning out to be a real challenge.
I tried using a temp file but then it outputs a black csv file.
I tried using unlink() but it just deletes the file before you can download it.
I'm guessing its a simple fix but I think it has to do with how I create the array for the fopen() function.
Unfortunately, it's the only way to make the array so that it out puts correctly.
(each domain stacking on top of each other in the same Colum of the csv file.) Using the 'a' method in the fopen() function is the only way to get all the domains in the file that I know of.
Any thoughts?
Here is the entire code:

```
<?php
$domnames = array('');


$domains = $_POST['domains'];
$domSep = explode(' ', $domains);
foreach ($domSep as $site) {
    $godaddycheck = 'https://in.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck='.$site.'';
    $namecomcheck = 'https://www.name.com/domain/search/'.$site.'';
    $registercomcheck = 'http://www.register.com/domain/search/wizard.rcmx?searchDomainName='.$site.'&searchPath=Default&searchTlds=';
    
    if(isset($_POST)){
        if (gethostbyname($site) != $site) {
             array_push($domnames, "$site" . " | Unavailable");      
        } else {
           array_push($domnames, "$site" . " | Available");
        }
        $full = array($domnames);
     
        // Open a file in write mode ('w') 
        $fp = fopen('domain_avalibilities.csv', 'a'); 
      
        // Loop through file pointer and a line 
        foreach ($full as $fields) { 
            fputcsv($fp, $fields); 
        } 
    } 
}     
?>
<div class="btndiv">        
    <a class="submitbtn" href="domain_avalibilities.csv" download>Download Results as CSV File</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just erase the content of your file `domain_avalibilities.csv`, since past datas are written to it. You can simply do `file_put_contents("domain_avalibilities.csv", "");`

Comment: fopen with option `"a"` say APPEND to the existing file if one exists, chance `"a"` to `"w"`

Comment: And move `fopen` outside of your `foreach` loop

Comment: And also add a fclose in a logical place as well.... Outside the loop

Comment: Using `file_put_contents()` basically avoid all this multiline mess, and can be easily remembered.

Comment: Thanks you guys! I'm sure those ideas would have worked but i actually solved the problem using if(file_exists(domain_availabilities.csv)){unlink(domain_availabilities.csv);}